# Style a given child based on the presence of an attribute on parent element?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<dialog>
   <div class="modal-box"></div>
</dialog>
```

The dialog it's the HTML Dialog element and has a `open` attribute when it's opened.

I want to assign some properties to `.modal-box` element based on parent dialog "state" (that is the `open` attribute).

I can't. The following doesn't work:

```
:open:[&>.modal-box]:bg-red-500
```

Any idea? Maybe it's not possibile?